# Using bit.ly as url shortener for Twitter Tweet button

Tags: twitter, bit.ly, url-shortener, twitter-button

I'm going to add a Twitter Tweet button - http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton - to some pages on my site.

The default url shortener they use is t.co

Is there a way to use bit.ly instead?

I would then be able to link it to my bit.ly account, and use bitly Analyze to evaluate the clicks on my links.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bit.ly api to generate a shortened url, and use it with your tweet button.